# Suppressing Headers while using DB2CLI

Tags: db2, bigsql

While using DB2CLI command,we get IBM copyright information and footer details. Is there any option to suppress header and footer information ?

```
echo "select CURRENT USER from dual"|db2cli execsql -dsn 'SAMPLE'
```

Output

```
PS C:\Users\Desktop> echo "select CURRENT USER from dual"|db2cli execsql -dsn 'SAMPLE'
IBM DATABASE 2 Interactive CLI Sample Program
(C) COPYRIGHT International Business Machines Corp. 1993,1996
All Rights Reserved
Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or
disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp.
> select CURRENT USER from dual
FetchAll:  Columns: 1
  1 
  TESTUSER 
FetchAll: 1 rows fetched.
>
```

Tried using set headers=off,which usually works in jsqsh but it doesn't work with DB2CLI,any leads are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There is no documented way to do this with the db2cli tool for currently shipping Db2-LUW versions up to V11.5.

There may be undocumented methods that IBM staff/contractors may disclose.

The tool `db2cli` is not intended as a general purpose SQL interface, instead it is for troubleshooting, verification, configuration, simple testing and also debugging.

Alternatives include:

- post-processing scripts to strip off anything you don't want, but you have to write these,
- use a Db2-client that includes the `db2` CLP which lets you use its `-x` option (among other options) and does not issue a copyright string. The Db2 Runtime client is small footprint and includes the `db2` CLP.
- use a scripting interface to Db2 (python, perl, bash) or a programmatic interface (c#, or other .net language) so you are in control, but these require relevant configuration.

Comment: Oh okay,thanks for info. I am using this in power-shell,am stripping of lines using hard coding, just wanted to know is there any better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the tool [db2batch](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002043.html). It allows to send SQL to Db2 and retrieve the results.

If you want full control, then go with what mao suggested in the other answer.